Definition of Riemann theta function
The Riemann-Theta function is usually defined as
$$
\theta(\xi): \mathbb{C}^g\to\mathbb{C}, \ \theta(\xi):=\sum_{\vec{m}\in\mathbb{Z}^g}e^{\frac{1}{2}\langle\vec{m},B\vec{m}\rangle+\langle \xi,\vec{m}\rangle}
$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is inner product and $B\in\text{GL}(g,\mathbb{C})$ satisfies $\text{Re}(B)<0$. However, there is also a Theta function defined by Abel map and the above $\theta$, namely,
$$
\Theta_d(P):=\theta(\mathcal{A}_{P_0}(P)-d), \ \ \mathcal{A}_{P_0}(P)=\int_{P_0}^P\vec{\omega}
$$
where $d\in\mathbb{C}^g$, $\vec{\omega}=(\omega_1,...,\omega_g)^T$ is the normalised basis of holomorphic differentials. I want to know why people (e.g. page 73, eq.(113,114) of https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~bobenko/Lehre/Skripte/RS.pdf) say "$\Theta_d$" is a entire function on the universal cover of $X$, where $X$ is a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$? Obviously, it is not well defined on $X$, because the Abel map is multivalued, if we don't consider its image in Jacobian. Also, what is meant by "analytic continuation along a cycle" of $\Theta_d$?
